# Convert iframe to string with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I need to convert an iframe to an string variable and then send to a server with php:

```
<center><iframe id="probando" src="prueba2.html" scrolling="auto" height="700"                width="800" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="probando"></iframe></center>
```

I do not know how I can continue...

Please help me. THANKS!!!

Comment: You need to convert that iframe into a string... Or are you looking for iframe contents?

Comment: This question can be interpreted several ways. Please put a little more effort into explaining your full issue. If all you want is the tag..that's one thing , if you want contents it's totally different

Comment: What I can to do its insert iframe content in a string variable adn then send to the server with php.

Comment: @LewiSS88 Your explanation does not explain too much. I will understand that you want the code loaded into the iframe, not the iframe code itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is to get contents inside the iframe, using jQuery. Note that this will work as expected in your own domain:

```
$(function(){
    $('#probando').on('load', function(){
        var str = $(this).contents().find('html').prop('outerHTML');
        console.log(str);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var html = document.getElementById("probando").outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
var string = $('center').html();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d0zr4t7j/2/)

or you can use

```
var string = $('#probando').closest('center').html();
```

Comment: what's to say there isn't other `center` tags in page? Would only get the first one and it may not be the right one.

Comment: @charlietfl in OP there is a `center` tag.

Comment: @erkaner and where there is one `<center>` in a page, you can be sure there is high probability there are others..iframe even has an id on it

Comment: It works with the portion of code that we saw from OP, but the good practice is to get the real target element 

Comment: @charlietfl it is an answer that solves the problem asked, that all matters.

Comment: The <center> tag It has nothing to do. What I can to do its insert iframe content in a string variable